# Is it possible to place marks at the end of a line?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, normal-mode, mark

Typical mark placement using `m` places the mark at the cursor. When the cursor is on the last character of a line, this means that jumping to that mark for the purpose of copying text starts the copying before the last character of the line.

For instance, if I have the sentence `Vim is a great editor.` and place a mark with my cursor on the `.` using `ma`, then move up some number of lines and hit `` y`a ``, I yank those lines plus `Vim is a great editor` but not the entire sentence.

Is there a way to place a mark after the period so that I can yank the entire line in situations like this?

I realize that if I never add more characters to that particular line, I can use `y'a`, but sometimes I want to maintain the flexibility to add more characters later.

If this is not possible, are there other features of Vim I can use to accomplish the same thing? For instance, is there some "yank until after cursor" command?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27754274/12542129).

> Another easy way is to just add `v` right after `y`, no setting or Visual
>   mode selection necessary.
>
> ```
> `a"ryv`b
> ```
>
> `` y`b `` yanks to mark `b` excluding the character under mark `b`, whereas `` yv`b ``
>   yanks to mark `b` including the character under it.
>
> See `:h o_v` for more info.